# Problem with items in mapping in appery.io

Tags: database, mapping

I'm trying to create an app with a list of items from a database in appery.io. I've created three collections each with a column that specifies their names of the items that I want to map to page content items (list items).
Here is how I've done it
[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot from database collection]

If all is well you can see the mapping from page content to the database items, but there is no option in the item list to link to name/type column. I've created database services using the database tool, but it doesn't provide the column.

How can I get the database service to provide the column that contains the items that I need?

Comment: Images can be posted as a part of your question. This is preferable over posting them as links. Please change the links to the actual images instead.

Comment: Images should be added as images and not added as links to images. This can be done in the editor or by adding a ! in front of a link you've added. I've also changed some wording in your question to make it more direct, personal and active. Being: "What must I do to make this work?"